# RestSharp reading special XML output with namespaces in it: "de.mydomain.ObjectName"

Tags: c#, wcf, xml-parsing, restsharp

I'm having trouble with removing/ignoring/matching the namespace that a web service service outputs in XML. Example:

```
<list>
   <de.domain.MyClass>
   </de.domain.MyClass>
</list>
```

The class looks like this:

```
namespace de.domain
{
  public class MyClass
  {
  }
}
```

This is how I access the XML at the moment:

```
IRestResponse<List<de.domain.MyClass>> response2 = client.Execute<List<de.domain.MyClass>>(request2);
```

Note: I'cant change the service output, thus I'm stuck with this type of XML content.

The XMLDeserializer of RestSharp currently simply returns NULL for the entire "Data" field inside "response2". Is there a way to solve this, for example by annotating the class?

Comment: Can you show how the Raw response looks like?

Comment: Yes indeed, but it's not really different from the XML as I gave as an example: "<list><de.domain.MyClass><name>dummy</name></de.domain.MyClass><de.domain.MyClass><name>dummy2</name></de.domain.MyClass></list>".

Comment: Try just naming your class DeDomainMyClass and doing `Execute<List<DeDomainMyClass>>()`

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you're not showing the whole complexity of what you are doing but have you thought about just using LINQ to XML to parse this and project the objects you want?

Comment: +1 Just grab the raw result with `Execute()` and pass RestResponse.Content (which is a string) to LINQ to XML or something else.